# Import OpenPGP key (on NixOS)

Tags: gnupg, password-management, openpgp, nixos

I am trying to import a PGP key into NixOS (exported from [Openkeychain](https://www.openkeychain.org/)). This key is used to encrypt and decrypt a list of passwords (with [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/)).

The following are the steps to reproduce the issue (you may follow this [guide](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android-app/export-android-openkeychain-private-key-to-pc/)):

1. In Openkeychain, do a backup of the key, write down the 36-digit code and save it;
2. In NixOS (let's say you have the backup key in your ~/Downloads folder), type the following:

```
nix-shell -p gnupg --run 'gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback ~/Downloads/backup_2021-09-16.sec.pgp | gpg --import'
```

This should result in a secret key imported but I only get a public key. Here is the full output:

```
gpg: unknown armor header: Passphrase-Format: numeric9x4
gpg: unknown armor header: Passphrase-Begin: 40
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026: public key "John Doe <john@doe.com>" imported
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026: "John Doe <john@doe.com>" not changed
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026/0x10D48E16F953D026: error sending to agent: Without pinentry
gpg: error building skey array: Sem pinentry
gpg: error reading '[stdin]': Without pinentry
gpg: import from '[stdin]' failed: Without pinentry
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
```

I tried adding the following entry to `gpg-agent.conf`, as suggested [here](https://sigkill.dk/writings/guides/nixos_pass.html):

```
pinentry-program /run/current-system/sw/bin/pinentry-curses
```

Then `$ gpgconf --reload gpg-agent` to reload the gpg-agent followed by the import command:

```
nix-shell -p gnupg --run 'gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback ~/Downloads/backup_2021-09-16.sec.pgp | gpg --import'
```

Will output this:

```
gpg: unknown armor header: Passphrase-Format: numeric9x4
gpg: unknown armor header: Passphrase-Begin: 40
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026: public key "John Doe <john@doe.com>" imported
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026: "John Doe <john@doe.com>" not changed
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026/0x10D48E16F953D026: error sending to agent: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: error building skey array: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: error reading '[stdin]': Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: import from '[stdin]' failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
```

Funny enough, doing the following will decrypt and output the public and private key on the terminal, with or without the above entry added to the `gpg-agent.conf` file:

```
nix-shell -p gnupg --run 'gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback < ~/Downloads/backup_2021-09-16.sec.pgp'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. You will need to decrypt it first into a text file. When prompted, use the code that was given to you by OpenKeychain when backing up the key:

```
nix-shell -p gnupg --run 'gpg -o ~/Downloads/backup_2021-09-16_decrypted.txt --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback < ~/Downloads/backup_2021-09-16.sec.pgp'
```

This will save your public and private keys in plain text, which you can confirm with the command `cat ~/Downloads/backup_2021-09-16_decrypted.txt`.

You can now import the keys with the following command (when prompted, insert the password for this key that you already use elsewhere, in the Password Store app for instance):

```
nix-shell -p gnupg --run 'gpg --import ~/Downloads/backup_2021-09-16_decrypted.txt'
```

Which should output something along these lines:

```
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026: "John Doe <john@doe.com>" not changed
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026: "John Doe <john@doe.com>" not changed
gpg: key 0x10D48E16F953D026: secret key imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 2
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
gpg:   secret keys imported: 1
```

Notice the `secret keys imported` line at the end. You can double check with the command `gpg --list-secret-keys`. If all went well, it should list your key's sec, uid, subkey and fingerprint.

Before that, you may need to enable the gpg-agent in your nixos configuration, like this:

```
services.gpg-agent = {
  enable = true;
};
```

This will create a `gpg-agent.conf` file for you (if you already have one, you will be prompted to either move it out of the way or use 'home-manager switch -b backup' to back it up automatically) with the following line in it:

```
pinentry-program /nix/store/bv018hrslwj37vpvgjrnqdpr0raj27ik-pinentry-1.1.0-gtk2/bin/pinentry
```